# Ant design Modal remove or change the black background

Tags: reactjs, background, modal-dialog, simplemodal, ant-design-pro

EDIT:

Hi, Thank You so much for your answer, it helps me a lot.  but do you know how to remove the lines background?
[image: please see this image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more information on the implementation you've done ?

Comment: You've edited your original question out, this Q&A pair no longer makes sense! Please edit your question to make sure someone coming here in the future will find useful information in the form of both a question and its answer(s).

Answer (score 5):

###### To hide the mask (background)

`mask={false}`

###### To change the style of mask(Background)

```
 maskStyle={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}
```

###### A complete example for experiment

[image: Prakash Ant React Modal]

```html
<Modal mask={true} maskStyle={{ backgroundColor: "red" }} title="Basic Modal" visible={isModalVisible} onOk={handleOk} onCancel={handleCancel}>
  <p>Some contents...</p>
  <p>Some contents...</p>
  <p>Some contents...</p>
</Modal>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank You so much for your answer, it helps me a lot. but do you know how to remove the lines background? see this pic https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gZjj.png

Comment: You can mark this answer and. try to replicate in the linked code sandbox. looks like a custom css /theme in your environment. so it needs to be available for debugging.

Comment: Not sure if you are using some background image

Comment: Hi, I don't use background image, when I change the size of the modal, it's not removing. see this pic https://i.stack.imgur.com/snfEh.png

Comment: It is hard to guess from an image.